# How to close the HttpServletResponse OutputStream when sending error

Tags: java, servlets, error-handling

In `HttpServlet.doGet(...)` I get the `OutputStream` from the `HttpServletResponse` with

```
resp.getOutputStream();
```

While writing to that output stream an exception occurs, and instead of the data, I want to send an error back

```
resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, "My error message");
```

How should I handle the output stream then?

I must probably close it. Does the already written data get sent to the client? Can I somehow discard that data so the client gets only the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image][image]The output stream will be send to client with content type as text/html.

As per the Java doc.

Sends an error response to the client using the specified status and clears the buffer. The server defaults to creating the response to look like an HTML-formatted server error page containing the specified message, setting the content type to "text/html".

If the response has already been committed, this method throws an IllegalStateException. After using this method, the response should be considered to be committed and should not be written to.

You can set error pages also for predefined response.sendError() codes in web.xml.

Edit: i have added a picture.

Comment: My observation so far is: if I close the stream, I get the IllegalStateException. If I leave the stream as is (not closing), and just call sendError() the client gets not answer ("no data received"). So I still don't know what to do.

Comment: If u close the stream before calling sendError, then u will get an IllegalStateException. if you are not closing the stream then, the String parameter in sendError is used to display a message to the client if an error page is not configured for that particular response code.

Answer (score 0):

When some exception occurs, it will not go to client. because you send an Error to client instead of data.

From Java doc.

> Sends an error response to the client using the specified status code and clearing the buffer.

so the client will not see any of the written data, and you should not care about the already written data. it will be cleaned up.

Comment: The doc says: If the response has already been committed, this method throws an IllegalStateException. What does "committed" mean? Should I close the stream?

Comment: It mean if you explicitly flush the buffer, the written data to client by calling `res.flushBuffer()`, and you attempt to use the writer again it will throw that kind of exception. or the response automatically flushed.